# Issue parsing JSON string containing dates

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string, object

I am trying parse string to json. I received string from the server but i am always receiving error of unexpected token e

```
var data = JSON.parse(result)
```

result is

```
{"success":true,"data":[{"carID":100110,"teamID":0,"carNO":"carNO1","simNO":"1212","machineNO":"800704","controlPassword":null,"machineType":null,"protocol":7,"routeway":0,"carType":null,"carBrand":null,"carColor":null,"installPlace":"7","installPerson":null,"businessPerson":null,"joinTime":new UtcDate(1460357844353),"overServiceTime":new UtcDate(1491840000000),"carRemark":null,"driver":null,"driverTel":null,"driverMobile":null,"driver2":null,"driver2Tel":null,"driver2Mobile":null,"password":null,"driverAddress":null,"driverFax":null,"driverCompany":null,"buyTime":null,"stoped":0,"specialRequest":"0","driverRemark":null,"regionAlarm":0,"regionID":0,"positionID":0,"notify":0,"notifyStart":new UtcDate(1460357844353),"notifyEnd":new UtcDate(1460357844353),"notifyText":null,"f_username":null,"isonline":0,"IfSendAlarmEmail":false,"AlarmEmail":null},{"carID":100111,"teamID":0,"carNO":"carNO2 TEst","simNO":"23","machineNO":"13000000005","controlPassword":null,"machineType":null,"protocol":7,"routeway":0,"carType":null,"carBrand":null,"carColor":null,"installPlace":"7","installPerson":null,"businessPerson":null,"joinTime":new UtcDate(1460358033120),"overServiceTime":new UtcDate(1491840000000),"carRemark":null,"driver":null,"driverTel":null,"driverMobile":null,"driver2":null,"driver2Tel":null,"driver2Mobile":null,"password":null,"driverAddress":null,"driverFax":null,"driverCompany":null,"buyTime":null,"stoped":0,"specialRequest":"0","driverRemark":null,"regionAlarm":0,"regionID":0,"positionID":0,"notify":0,"notifyStart":new UtcDate(1460358033120),"notifyEnd":new UtcDate(1460358033120),"notifyText":null,"f_username":null,"isonline":0,"IfSendAlarmEmail":false,"AlarmEmail":null}]}
```

I have tested on an online jsonparse http://json.parser.online.fr/

It is also returning the same error.

If I am not mistaken, the date is in a wrong format but I am not allowed to touch the server side. What have I done wrong?

Comment: seems like this is a problem on your client side, I can parse that in the mentioned parser without any errors.

Comment: Are you use you are not trying to parse an object? `console.log(typeof result);`

Comment: Parses fine for me, both in the online parser and in a test harness I just created.

Comment: Sorry guys, I pasted the wrong string

Comment: I have updated the result. My bad in pasting the wrong string

Comment: ""joinTime":new UtcDate(1460357844353)" - not valid JSON. So, the server is wrong here.

Comment: `new` is not part of JSON specifications. It is valid JavaScript but not valid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dates are obviously not valid JSON. But if you don't have access to the server, you could convert these dates to regular timestamps by using Regex:

```
// Will convert   new UtcDate(1460357844353)      to      1460357844353
var data = JSON.parse( result.replace(/new UtcDate\(([0-9]+)\)/gi, "$1") );
```

#### JS Fiddle demo

Comment: This is just smart. Thank you blex!